# How can I convert this column value to an integer?

Tags: c#

My C# code looks like this:

```
myNum = dt.Columns[0];
```

myNum is an integer and dt is a datatable.  The value in column 0 of dt is a string ("12"), but I'd like to convert it to an integer.  How can I do this?
I've tried:

```
myNum = int.Parse(dt.Columns[0]);
```

...but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: "but that doesn't work"... can you be more specific?

Comment: why do you say it doesn't work ? it throws an exception?

Comment: Sure!  The editor (Visual Studio) complains when I try to use int.Parse.  Says "The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The values are stored in rows and not columns. Try this instead:

```
myNum = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Comment: It would be better to use int.TryParse(..) unless you are certain the value will always be an int.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty certain the value will always be an int.

Answer (score 9):

Your parse wasn't working because the parse method takes a string, and the data comes back as a simple object.

Also, the data is in the rows, so you have two options really, (I prefer the first):

```
// This converts the object directly to an integer
myNum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]); 

// This converts the object to a string, and then parses it into an integer
myNum = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Comment: You may or may not need to test for nulls.

Answer (score 3):

if Parse throws an exception, this means dt.Columns[0] is not a valid input. If you want to avoid exception, you can use int.TryParse which returns a boolean telling if the conversion was done or not successfully

**EDIT**: BTW, Darin must be right: your value is not stored in a column but in a cell

Answer (score 1):

Use TryParse method to parse the Value :

```
int myNum = 0;
int.TryParse(dt.rows[0][0].ToString() , out myNum);
```

with above code , If an error occurs , The value of variable will be zero

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0])
```

The above would be better, if you are dealing with a variety of types, eg doubles (1.0).